# Powershell Calculate totals from array from multiple rows

Tags: powershell

I have an array with the following data.  I need to figure out how to combine the data and report it out based on JobName.  If the job only has a status of success it would have a total of 33, if it has three status's it need to count all the job names together.

```
JobName  Status  Count
Job #1   Success 33
Job #2   Failed  9
Job #2   Success 32
Job #2   Warning 5
```

Here is some of the code I have tried.

```
$arrAllTasksBk = $taskListBk | Sort JobName | Select @{Name="JobName"; Expression = {$_.jobname}}, Status 
$arrAllTasksBk = $arrAllTasksBk | Group-object 'JobName', status |
 Select-Object @{n='JobName';e={$_.Group[0].'JobName'}}, @{n='Status';e={$_.Group[0].Status}}, Count

$arrAllTasksBk = $arrAllTasksBk | Sort JobName |  Select
            @{Name="JobName"; Expression = {$_.jobname}},
            @{Name="Total"; Expression = {$_.Count | Where {($_.status -match "Success") -or ($_.status -match "Warning")-or ($_.status -match "Failed")}}},
            @{Name="Failed"; Expression = {$_.Count | Where {$_.status -match"Failed"}}},
            @{Name="SuccessRate"; Expression = {$_.Count | Where {($_.status -match "Success") -or ($_.status -match "Warning")-or ($_.status -match "Failed")} / {$_.status -match "Success" }}}
```

Comment: could you please export a sample of the data to json and edit post with data? I cant tell if you are getting array of hashtables or multidimensional array or a flat array. There is not enough information for me personally to provide a solution.

Comment: take a look at the `Group-Object` cmdlet. that can group on a property and then you can sum the `.Count` properties of the items with the same `.JobName`. ///// if you can, change the job names to remove the embedded space AND the `#` since both of those can cause odd problems with property names.

Comment: The job names were changed just to show the type of data.  I am getting data from Veeam and trying to show a success rate for different jobs.  It would take a add the warning and success counts and then divide by the total count for each job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one way to get those numbers. delete or comment out the items you don't want in the final output ... [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
JobName, Status, Count
Job #1, Success, 33
Job #2, Failed,  9
Job #2, Success, 32
Job #2, Warning, 5
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$GroupedInStuff = $InStuff |
    Group-Object -Property JobName

$Results = foreach ($GIS_Item in $GroupedInStuff)
    {
    $Success = [int]($GIS_Item.Group.Where({$_.Status -eq 'Success'}))[0].Count
    $Failed = [int]($GIS_Item.Group.Where({$_.Status -eq 'Failed'}))[0].Count
    $Warning = [int]($GIS_Item.Group.Where({$_.Status -eq 'Warning'}))[0].Count
    $Total = $Success + $Failed + $Warning
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        JobName = $GIS_Item.Name
        TotalCount = $Total
        Success = $Success
        Failed = $Failed
        # to remove the "Warning" items, comment out the next line
        Warning = $Warning
        # to get an int percent [70 instead of 69.57]
        #    use the following line
        # SuccessPct = [int]('{0:N0}' -f ($Success / $Total * 100))
        SuccessPct = [decimal]('{0:N2}' -f ($Success / $Total * 100))
        }
    }

$Results
```

output ...

```
JobName    : Job #1
TotalCount : 33
Success    : 33
Failed     : 0
Warning    : 0
SuccessPct : 100.00

JobName    : Job #2
TotalCount : 46
Success    : 32
Failed     : 9
Warning    : 5
SuccessPct : 69.57
```

Comment: Perfect this is what I was missing, thanks for the help.

Comment: @etherk - you are most welcome! glad to help ... [*grin*]